# In the default Visual Studio Blazor WebAssembly app, how would you move the WeatherForecast class into a separate project?

Tags: visual-studio, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-webassembly

If I could figure this out, I could redo my Blazor Server app as a WebAssembly app.

Out of the box, the WebAssembly Solution appears as follows with the WeatherForecast class in FetchData.razor.: 
 [image: Starting Solution]

I want to refactor this so that the WeatherForecast class is moved from FetchData.razor to WeatherForecast.cs in a separate C# Class Library project.

[image: Target Solution]

What changes to which bits are needed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weather forecast class, in a separate class library, looks like this:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;
namespace WeatherForecastNamespace
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
        public static async Task<WeatherForecast[]?> GetWeatherForecasts(HttpClient Http)
        {
            return await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
        }
    }
}
```

And the FetchData.razor @code block, with the old code commented out, looks like this:

```
@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
        forecasts = await WeatherForecast.GetWeatherForecasts(Http);
    }

    //public class WeatherForecast
    //{
    //    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    //    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    //    public string? Summary { get; set; }

    //    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    //}
}
```

If there are problems with this approach, I'd appreciate hearing about them.